# How do I know the date of the key entry in the known_hosts file

Tags: linux, ssh

Suppose if I exchange keys between 2 servers and want to know the exact date of ssh keys entry in the known_hosts file then how will I be able to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can't see that information - more info: [What do the different parts of “known_hosts” entries mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/331080/what-do-the-different-parts-of-known-hosts-entries-mean)

However, it's perfectly normal to just delete the known_hosts file and add new servers again. Else, you have to manually keep track of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create a git/SVN/whatever repo for this file and `git push` it each time you connect to a new server. To simplify things:

```bsh
cat ~/bin/myssh

#! /bin/bash

pushd
ssh "$@"
cd ~/.ssh && git push
popd
```